# How to execute alternatives with puppet?

Tags: java, tomcat, puppet, rhel

I write a puppet module that will install on a RHEL 7 server Tomcat 7 and Oracle Java 8. The problem is that RH Tomcat's package has a requirement for OpenJDK. 
Installing the packages manually, I can solve the Java version issue easily by running the "alternatives" script and manually selecting the correct Java version.

**UPDATE:**
Using bash, I can run the alternatives quite easily:

```
alternatives --set java $(rpm -ql oracle-java-1.8.0 | grep -e "jre/bin$")
```

So, what I need now, is to "execute" the

```
$(rpm -ql oracle-java-1.8.0 | grep -e "jre/bin$")
```

using puppet. I would like to avoid facter, and custom fact scripts because I don't have the experience to actually do it.

So, any ideas?

Comment: Ideal would be to update your module to not discern between Oracle Java 8 and OpenJDK 8, which are virtually identical anyway.  I'm told that Oracle adds a few things to its self-branded version, but I couldn't tell you what they are, and the difference does not matter for most people.

Comment: The module is created for an application server cluster and all applications require Oracle Java 8, so I don't need to create a generic one (which is easy anyway).

Comment: I'm saying that it is unlikely that the applications actually do require Oracle 8 instead of OpenJDK 8, except possibly in a "that's what the RPM dependency says" kind of sense.  In that case, it might make your life simpler to just run them on OpenJDK.

Comment: Totally agree John, but I cannot overrule the business, unfortunately.